# Spark SQL(Hive query through HiveContext) always creating 31 partitions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

I am running hive queries using HiveContext from my Spark code. No matter which query I run and how much data it is, it always generates 31 partitions. Anybody knows the reason? Is there a predefined/configurable setting for it? I essentially need more partitions.

I using this code snippet to execute hive query:

var pairedRDD = hqlContext.sql(hql).rdd.map(...)

I am using Spark 1.3.1

Thanks, 
Nitin

Answer (score 0):

The number of partitions in an RDD is the same as the number of partitions in the RDD on which it depends, with a couple exceptions: the *coalesce* transformation allows creating an RDD with fewer partitions than its parent RDD, the *union* transformation creates an RDD with the sum of its parents’ number of partitions, and *cartesian* creates an RDD with their product.
To increase number of partitions

- Use the repartition transformation, which will trigger a shuffle.
- Configure your InputFormat to create more splits.
- Write the input data out to HDFS with a smaller block size.

This link [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) has good explanation of how the number of partitions are defined and how to increase the number of partitions.